# File not found when using objshell.run -- vbscript

Tags: vbscript

When i try to run the script it throws up error that the file does not exist..
On the script it does echos file exists though.
Have tried with 
objshell.run """apppath""" but no luck.. :(
Please help.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
AppPath =  objshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ProgramFiles%") + "\ERUNT\ERUNT.EXE"
wscript.echo apppath
if fx = objfso.FileExists("apppath") then
wscript.Echo "File Exists"
objshell.run apppath
Else
Wscript.echo "File Does not Exist"
end IF
```

Answer (score 5):

Apppath contains spaces.  Try surrounding it in quotes.

```
objshell.run vbQuote & apppath & vbQuote
```

Comment: Spot on... i used "objshell.run(Chr(34) & apppath & Chr(34)" instead... Thanks...

Comment: I'm glad tha helped.  If you are satisfied with this answer, please Accept it.