# Getting "file not found" error

Tags: vbscript

I don't understand why this code:

```
Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
Set oCMD = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Sub OpenFile(file)
  oCMD.run file
End Sub

Sub OpenCMD
  oCMD.run "%COMAPEC% /c start cmd"
End Sub

Sub Blink
  oCMD.run "%COMAPEC% /c exit"
End Sub

Sub Wait(seconds)
  oCMD.run "%COMSPEC% /c ping -n " & seconds+1 & " 127.0.0.1", 0, True
End Sub

Sub PromptCommand(command)
  oCMD.run "%COMAPEC% /c " & command
End Sub

Blink
Wait("0.5")
OpenCMD
Wait("7")
OpenFile("C:\Documents and Settings\Scott\Desktop\Lemmings\LEMMINGS.bat")
```

gives me the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With line 13 being

```
oCMD.run "%COMAPEC% /c exit"
```

I'd suspect that you simply mistyped the environment variable. Replace every occurrence of `%COMAPEC%` in your script with `%COMSPEC%`.

And, of course, *always* put paths between double quotes, as [@Ekkehard.Horner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25044323/1630171) recommended. You can simplify the handling by using a quoting function like this:

```
Function qq(str) : qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34) : End Function

oCMD.Run qq(file)
```

which is a bit better readable than a bunch of string concatenations.

Answer (score 1):

Start with quoting the command line passed to .Run:

```
oCMD.run """" & file & """""
```

instead of:

```
oCMD.run file
```

(cf. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358993/file-not-found-when-using-objshell-run-vbscript))