# objShell.Run Error: File Not Found

Tags: vbscript, hta

I'm writing a HTA script **"Opslag.hta"**, from which I want to open another HTA script **"update.hta"**.

I'm trying to open **"update.hta"**, which is located in a subfolder (include) to the primary script:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
UpdatePath = "include\update.hta"
objShell.Run (chr(34) & UpdatePath & chr(34))
```

However I'm getting the error **"File Not Found"** and when I'm prompted if I want to continue running scripts and press **"Yes"** the **"update.hta"** actually opens.

I have tried to move the "update.hta" script to different locations and even tried to specify the full path for "update.hta" in "UpdatePath". I have tried with **vbQuote**, double backslashes (since the "Opslag.hta" is located in a path with spaces) and every possible solution I could find, without succes.

This thread: [File not found when using objshell.run -- vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358993/file-not-found-when-using-objshell-run-vbscript), did not help me unfortunately.

I'm running on a Windows 7, 64 bit - don't know if that has anything to do with it.

I really hope someone here has the answer as I'm about to got nuts! =)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If '"update.hta" actually opens' then the 'File not found' error must be caused by code you didn't publish.

Comment: It seems the error is being generated inside `update.hta`

Comment: When error occurs, open task manager, and check if there are two mshta.exe processes. If so then the error is caused by the second HTA.

Comment: @MCND: You were right! The error was caused inside the `update.hta`. 

When testing the `update.hta` earlier I justed opened the script myself. Apparently when opening `update.hta` from my primary HTA `Opslag.hta`, it changes some path variables which was set inside `update.hta`. 

Anyone, problem solved! Thank you! =)

Comment: @MCND: Please write your answer and I will acknowledge it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note*: I'm not sure this is really an answer, but as requested... this is how i saw it:

Reading the code

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
UpdatePath = "include\update.hta"
objShell.Run (chr(34) & UpdatePath & chr(34))
```

there are two alternatives

1. `update.hta` can not be found. In this case there will be an error and the `hta` file will not be opened
2. `update.hta` can be found. In this case there will be no error and the `hta` file will be opened

But none of these alternatives match the observed behaviour. The `hta` file is opened, so it is found. But a error is shown. Since the code in the caller does not include anything that could case the error, the source of the error should be in the called file.

Comment: Well your deduction helped me find the error, so for that I accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, it seems you already got the answer to the problem.

It's probably worthwhile to ask the relevant commenter to post their answer so you can mark it as answered.

Whenever I work with paths, I get paranoid about using relative paths. As a general rule, try to use absolute path names instead of relative paths.

For your specific example, we should attempt to derive the absolute path of `update.hta` from `Opslag.hta`. We can do this by using document.location from the HTML Dom. For instance, on my computer, I have `Opslag.hta` under `C:\Temp\HTA\Opslag.hta`:

1. `document.href` returns `"file:///C:/Temp/HTA/Opslag.hta"`
2. So, some string manipulation is required to turn it into `"C:\Temp\HTA\Opslag.hta"`
3. Then we can use the FileSystemObject to extract the `"C:\Temp\HTA"` folder.

Another tip is Chr(34) is the same as """". Generally, if you want to escape a double quotes in VBScript you use a pair of double quotes. e.g. If you want `John says: "Hello!"` as a VBScript string, it's `"John says: ""Hello!"""`.

Here's an example code illustrating the result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Opslag.hta test</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script language="VBScript">
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
htaPath = Replace(Replace(document.location, "file:///", ""), "/", "\")
htaFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(htaPath)
updatePath = htaFolder + "\include\update.hta"
MsgBox updatePath
objShell.Run """" & updatePath & """"
</script>
</html>
```

BTW, this is just an example. I would not normally put large scripts `<script>` after the `<body>` however, it's generally good practice if your `<script>` works with the `HTML Document` that you wait for the entire DOM to load, i.e. place it after `<body>`.